# How does double star work in vim?

Tags: argument-list

When I run `shopt -s globstar; ls -1 tests/**/Helpers/**/*.php` in `bash` I get:

```
tests/Helpers/Layout.php
tests/Helpers/Link.php
tests/Helpers/LinksPage.php
tests/Helpers/LiqpayRedirect.php
tests/Helpers/LoginPage.php
tests/Helpers/Project.php
tests/Helpers/ProjectsPage.php
tests/Helpers/QueriesPage.php
tests/Helpers/Query.php
tests/Helpers/User.php
tests/Selenium/Helpers/Layout.php
tests/Selenium/Helpers/LinksPage.php
tests/Selenium/Helpers/ProjectsPage.php
tests/Selenium/Helpers/QueriesPage.php
tests/Selenium/Helpers/RegisterPage.php
tests/Selenium/Helpers/User.php
```

But doing `args tests/**/Helpers/**/*.php` in `vim` defines argument list consisting only of files with `Selenium` in path. Am I doing it wrong? What exactly are the rules? From the docs it sounds like it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### tl;dr

a bug in `vim`

#### how to reproduce/inspect

1. Build `vim` from sources with the following patch:

   ```
   diff --git a/src/misc1.c b/src/misc1.c
   index 2d635d677..44ccf4a7a 100644
   --- a/src/misc1.c
   +++ b/src/misc1.c
   @@ -10171,8 +10171,18 @@ unix_expandpath(
        char_u *path,
        int        wildoff,
        int        flags,      /* EW_* flags */
   -    int        didstar)    /* expanded "**" once already */
   -{
   +    int        didstar, int __l)   /* expanded "**" once already */
   +{
   +FILE *__fp;
   +int __i;
   +__fp = fopen("../log", "a");
   +fprintf(__fp, "%*sunix_expandpath: path: %s, wildoff: %i, flags: %x, didstar: %i\n", __l * 4, "", path, wildoff, flags, didstar);
   +if (gap->ga_len) {
   +    fprintf(__fp, "%*s    gap:\n", __l * 4, "");
   +    for (__i = 0; __i < gap->ga_len; __i++)
   +   fprintf(__fp, "%*s        %s\n", __l * 4, "", ((char **)gap->ga_data)[__i]);
   +}
   +fclose(__fp);
        char_u *buf;
        char_u *path_end;
        char_u *p, *s, *e;
   @@ -10274,6 +10284,9 @@ unix_expandpath(
       regmatch.rm_ic = p_fic; /* ignore case when 'fileignorecase' is set */
        if (flags & (EW_NOERROR | EW_NOTWILD))
       ++emsg_silent;
   +__fp = fopen("../log", "a");
   +fprintf(__fp, "%*s    pat: %s\n", __l * 4, "", pat);
   +fclose(__fp);
        regmatch.regprog = vim_regcomp(pat, RE_MAGIC);
        if (flags & (EW_NOERROR | EW_NOTWILD))
       --emsg_silent;
   @@ -10292,12 +10305,15 @@ unix_expandpath(
        {
       STRCPY(s, path_end + 1);
       ++stardepth;
   -   (void)unix_expandpath(gap, buf, (int)(s - buf), flags, TRUE);
   +   (void)unix_expandpath(gap, buf, (int)(s - buf), flags, TRUE, __l + 1);
       --stardepth;
        }

        /* open the directory for scanning */
        *s = NUL;
   +__fp = fopen("../log", "a");
   +fprintf(__fp, "%*s    inspecting: %s\n", __l * 4, "", *buf == NUL ? "." : buf);
   +fclose(__fp);
        dirp = opendir(*buf == NUL ? "." : (char *)buf);

        /* Find all matching entries */
   @@ -10308,6 +10324,9 @@ unix_expandpath(
           dp = readdir(dirp);
           if (dp == NULL)
           break;
   +__fp = fopen("../log", "a");
   +fprintf(__fp, "%*s    entry: %s\n", __l * 4, "", dp->d_name);
   +fclose(__fp);
           if ((dp->d_name[0] != '.' || starts_with_dot
               || ((flags & EW_DODOT)
                   && dp->d_name[1] != NUL
   @@ -10327,7 +10346,7 @@ unix_expandpath(
               STRCPY(buf + len, "/**");
               STRCPY(buf + len + 3, path_end);
               ++stardepth;
   -           (void)unix_expandpath(gap, buf, len + 1, flags, TRUE);
   +           (void)unix_expandpath(gap, buf, len + 1, flags, TRUE, __l + 1);
               --stardepth;
           }

   @@ -10336,12 +10355,15 @@ unix_expandpath(
           {
               /* need to expand another component of the path */
               /* remove backslashes for the remaining components only */
   -           (void)unix_expandpath(gap, buf, len + 1, flags, FALSE);
   +           (void)unix_expandpath(gap, buf, len + 1, flags, FALSE, __l + 1);
           }
           else
           {
               stat_T  sb;

   +__fp = fopen("../log", "a");
   +fprintf(__fp, "%*s    found: %s\n", __l * 4, "", buf);
   +fclose(__fp);
               /* no more wildcards, check if there is a match */
               /* remove backslashes for the remaining components only */
               if (*path_end != NUL)
   @@ -10362,6 +10384,9 @@ unix_expandpath(
               }
    #endif
               addfile(gap, buf, flags);
   +__fp = fopen("../log", "a");
   +fprintf(__fp, "%*s    added: %s\n", __l * 4, "", buf);
   +fclose(__fp);
               }
           }
           }
   diff --git a/src/os_unix.c b/src/os_unix.c
   index ff0b0e88d..40c1236fe 100644
   --- a/src/os_unix.c
   +++ b/src/os_unix.c
   @@ -6255,7 +6255,7 @@ mch_expandpath(
        char_u *path,
        int        flags)      /* EW_* flags */
    {
   -    return unix_expandpath(gap, path, 0, flags, FALSE);
   +    return unix_expandpath(gap, path, 0, flags, FALSE, 0);
    }
    #endif

   diff --git a/src/proto/misc1.pro b/src/proto/misc1.pro
   index 4e299e5f9..50319b6d5 100644
   --- a/src/proto/misc1.pro
   +++ b/src/proto/misc1.pro
   @@ -98,7 +98,7 @@ void fast_breakcheck(void);
    int expand_wildcards_eval(char_u **pat, int *num_file, char_u ***file, int flags);
    int expand_wildcards(int num_pat, char_u **pat, int *num_files, char_u ***files, int flags);
    int match_suffix(char_u *fname);
   -int unix_expandpath(garray_T *gap, char_u *path, int wildoff, int flags, int didstar);
   +int unix_expandpath(garray_T *gap, char_u *path, int wildoff, int flags, int didstar, int __l);
    void remove_duplicates(garray_T *gap);
    int gen_expand_wildcards(int num_pat, char_u **pat, int *num_file, char_u ***file, int flags);
    void addfile(garray_T *gap, char_u *f, int flags);
   ```

   ```
   $ ./configure CFLAGS='-g -O0 -gdwarf-2 -g3' CXXFLAGS='-g -O0 -gdwarf-2 -g3'
   $ make
   ```

   `-g` - add debugging information
   `-O0` - reduce optimizations
   `-gdwarf-2 -g3` - include information about [preprocessor macros](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_17.html)
2. Create test directory:

   ```
   $ mkdir -p a/b b
   $ touch a/b/c b/c
   $ tree
   .
   ├── a
   │   └── b
   │       └── c
   └── b
       └── c
   ```
3. Run `gdb`:

   ```
   $ rm ../log; gdb --args ../vim/src/vim -u NONE
   (gdb) break mch_expandpath
   (gdb) r
   :args **/b/**/*
   (gdb) n
   ```
4. `cat ../log`:

   ```
   unix_expandpath: path: **/b/**/*, wildoff: 0, flags: f, didstar: 0
       pat: .*
       (1) unix_expandpath: path: b/**/*, wildoff: 0, flags: f, didstar: 1
           pat: .*
           inspecting: b/
           entry: ..
           entry: c
           unix_expandpath: path: b/c/**/*, wildoff: 4, flags: f, didstar: 1
               pat: .*
               inspecting: b/c/
           unix_expandpath: path: b/c/*, wildoff: 4, flags: f, didstar: 0
               pat: .*
               inspecting: b/c/
           entry: .
       inspecting: .
       entry: a
       unix_expandpath: path: a/**/b/**/*, wildoff: 2, flags: f, didstar: 1
           pat: .*
           inspecting: a/
           entry: b
           unix_expandpath: path: a/b/**/b/**/*, wildoff: 4, flags: f, didstar: 1
               pat: .*
               inspecting: a/b/
               entry: ..
               entry: c
               unix_expandpath: path: a/b/c/**/b/**/*, wildoff: 6, flags: f, didstar: 1
                   pat: .*
                   inspecting: a/b/c/
               unix_expandpath: path: a/b/c/b/**/*, wildoff: 6, flags: f, didstar: 0
                   pat: .*
                   unix_expandpath: path: a/b/c/b/*, wildoff: 8, flags: f, didstar: 1
                       pat: .*
                       inspecting: a/b/c/b/
                   inspecting: a/b/c/b/
               entry: .
           unix_expandpath: path: a/b/b/**/*, wildoff: 4, flags: f, didstar: 0
               pat: .*
               unix_expandpath: path: a/b/b/*, wildoff: 6, flags: f, didstar: 1
                   pat: .*
                   inspecting: a/b/b/
               inspecting: a/b/b/
           entry: ..
           entry: .
       (2) unix_expandpath: path: a/b/**/*, wildoff: 2, flags: f, didstar: 0
           pat: .*
           unix_expandpath: path: a/b/*, wildoff: 4, flags: f, didstar: 1
               pat: .*
               inspecting: a/b/
               entry: ..
               entry: c
               found: a/b/c
               added: a/b/c
               entry: .
           inspecting: a/b/
           entry: ..
           entry: c
           unix_expandpath: path: a/b/c/**/*, wildoff: 6, flags: f, didstar: 1
               gap:
                   a/b/c
               pat: .*
               inspecting: a/b/c/
           unix_expandpath: path: a/b/c/*, wildoff: 6, flags: f, didstar: 0
               gap:
                   a/b/c
               pat: .*
               inspecting: a/b/c/
           entry: .
       entry: b
       unix_expandpath: path: b/**/b/**/*, wildoff: 2, flags: f, didstar: 1
           gap:
               a/b/c
           pat: .*
           inspecting: b/
           entry: ..
           entry: c
           unix_expandpath: path: b/c/**/b/**/*, wildoff: 4, flags: f, didstar: 1
               gap:
                   a/b/c
               pat: .*
               inspecting: b/c/
           unix_expandpath: path: b/c/b/**/*, wildoff: 4, flags: f, didstar: 0
               gap:
                   a/b/c
               pat: .*
               unix_expandpath: path: b/c/b/*, wildoff: 6, flags: f, didstar: 1
                   gap:
                       a/b/c
                   pat: .*
                   inspecting: b/c/b/
               inspecting: b/c/b/
           entry: .
       unix_expandpath: path: b/b/**/*, wildoff: 2, flags: f, didstar: 0
           gap:
               a/b/c
           pat: .*
           unix_expandpath: path: b/b/*, wildoff: 4, flags: f, didstar: 1
               gap:
                   a/b/c
               pat: .*
               inspecting: b/b/
           inspecting: b/b/
       entry: ..
       entry: .
   ```

Here we can see that if `unix_expandpath (1)` had received `didstar == 0`, as `unix_expandpath (2)` did, `b/c` would have [matched](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.0.1427/src/misc1.c#L10290).

Answer (score 5):

You can check with `echo glob2regpat('tests/**/Helpers/**/*.php')` to what regular expression this will be translated. This returns: `^tests[\/].*[\/]Helpers[\/].*[\/].*\.php$`, so it will look only for a Helpers directory which is located below any directory underneath the tests directory.

Comment: So [this](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#wildcards) is not particularly true: "** matches anything, **including nothing**, recurses into directories" More importantly, where's `glob2regpath()` coming from? My `vim` says: "Unknown function."

Comment: update your vim

Comment: My `vim` is `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Oct 30 2016 15:29:26) Included patches: 1-55`. Maybe that is some distributive-specific function? I'm running Arch Linux. And I can't find it in [the docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/search.php?search=glob2regpath%28%29&docs=help) and Google.

Comment: the correct function name is `glob2regpat` (without the **h**). I had an error in the first version of the answer and have since then updated it.

Comment: @x-yuri `**` works as expected if I do `:args tests/**/Helpers/*.txt` - the regex turns out to be `^tests/.*/Helpers/.*\.php$` - which isn't functionally different as a regex in the portion of interest (`tests/.*/Helpers`), so I think this must be a bug in the handling of multiple `**`

Comment: @muru `^tests/.*/Helpers/.*\.php$` won't match `tests/Helpers/1.php`, so it's functionally different from `bash` behavior. As such, it's a bug in the handling of not just multiple `**`.

Comment: @x-yuri no, `/.*/` should match an empty path - in POSIX-following environments, any number of consecutive `/` (except a leading `//`) is equivalent to a single `/`. Part of the problem is that while `glob2regpat` returns a similar looking regex, I don't think the code actually uses regular expressions to check paths. The main problem is apparently the check for expanding `**` to an empty path - it only allows it to be [done once for a pattern](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/caa55b65c204946d160c1b743c5f8f3b506dc4d3/src/misc2.c#L4615).

Comment: @muru The way I see it, if the regex is like so `a/.*/b`, `a/b` won't match it. But if the regex is not used by `vim` itself, that's a different matter. Having that said, good point about `**` expanding to empty string only once for a pattern.

Comment: @muru yes it does. Vim uses internally regexes to match patterns.

Comment: @muru From my experience it happens in [`misc1.c`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14681/1553).